# Entourage Connecting to Exchange 2007 over VPN

Tags: email, mac-osx, exchange-2007, mac

I have a user connecting to the network over a SSL VPN by Forticlient, He is using a mac and needs to connect to the exchange server, so he is running Entourage. Who ever set it up for him previously got it to work and got his email synced. But now he has come to me because the mailbox says it is not connected. Does anyone have any ideas. I hope this is enough info, it is all I have figured out so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initially set it up within the network and not over the VPN, then you may need to look at the settings for the account and make sure you are using the FQDN for the Exchange server.

Comment: I tried the FQDN, that did not work, so I decided to try using the IP address, and that took care of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you allow RPC access over HTTP? I have a user on our network that has been sucessful is using Entourage to connect using RPC over HTTP, without a VPN connection being required.

Everything can be setto use HTTPS so it is still encrypted and secure.

I realize that this may or may not be possible in your enviornonment, however I just want to make sure that you were aware that like Outlook, Entourage can also leverage the RPC over HTTP protocal for easy remote access.

Answer (score 1):

If the computer is not connected to the domain, which often Mac are not in my organization, you will need to use the IP address of the system for it to correctly find the server.